# My first app isn't working and it crashes: UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

I am new to Android and I started making my first application following tutorials and such. However, when I click the run button it gives me following error on the logcat from which I count not identify where the error is. Hence, here is my code in hope of some advice. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText firstnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberinput);
                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttextview);
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstnum.getText().toString()) ;
                int result = num1 * num1;
                resultTextView.setText(result + "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCat after fixing the render problem :

```
7-16 01:27:14.359 10870-10870/com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp, PID: 10870
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp/com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x4
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x4
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelOffset(TypedArray.java:546)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:2685)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:476)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:820)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

And the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/square_of_the_number_is"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberinput" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Resulttextview"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="@string/the_result_is"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resulttextview"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="@string/_0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/Optional"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Resulttextview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:text="@string/butan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberinput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/number_in_here"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resulttextview" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the manifest.Xml as requested in the comments :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abarimess.myfirstapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your logcat refers to an issue with converting a value to a dimension. Could you please [edit] your question to also include your layout XML?

Comment: sure and done sir

Comment: Did you add your `MainActivity` as a launcher in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Please share your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout xml file, you have two separate `TextView` which are the following.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Resulttextview"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="@string/the_result_is"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttextview"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="@string/_0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="@color/Optional"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Resulttextview" />
```

Name of both text views are identical except the first one has started with a capital `R`. You might consider the name of the first `TextView` to something else like `resulttextview1` like the following.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttextview1"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="@string/the_result_is"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resulttextview"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="@string/_0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="@color/Optional"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resulttextview1" />
```

Please avoid naming layout identifiers with capital letters. Use underscores instead (e.g. `result_text_view`).

Another potential problem in your code is, if there is nothing entered in your `EditText` the app will crash again with a `NullPointerException` as the value which will be returned from `firstnum.getText().toString()` will have the null value.

In this case, you might consider adding a null checking here.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText firstnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberinput);
    TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttextview);

    // Add a null check here for safety
    if(firstnum.getText().toString() == null) return;

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstnum.getText().toString()) ;
    int result = num1 * num1;
    resultTextView.setText(result + "");
}
```

You will get `NumberFormatException` in case of entering a string in your `EditText` other than a number. So you might need to handle that case as well. However, this can be ignored in case of handling only numbers in your `EditText`.

Comment: the app actually runs now i think the problem was because of the same name except for the capitalism as you mentioned above , and i will be using underscores from now on

Comment: Great to know that you have solved your problem. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

this Is because you should to instance

```
EditText firstnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberinput);
```

Out of method on click listener.

Comment: sorry but no i don't think this the solution just tried it

Answer (score 1):

The `layout_editor_absoluteX` attribute for the resulttextview in your layout XML is referencing `spotShadowAlpha`, which is an integer which can't be explicitly converted to a [dimension](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension), as it doesn't contain any units.

You should update this value to a dimension. For example:

`app:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"`

Obviously, you'll need to change this example up to fit the rest of your layout.

Comment: thanks i realized that like 5 seconds ago so i removed the spotshadow alpha and the error is now gone but when i run the app on my phone it says "unfortunately app has stopped working " will update the xml right now

Comment: No problem, it's a start at least! If this XML doesn't solve your issue and you get another significantly different error in your logcat, I would suggest asking asking about this in another question, as it would *probably* point to another unrelated problem in your app. Regardless, good luck! :)